# Voltage inverter with output drop

Tags: power-supply, power, pwm, inverter

Could someone help me on an inverter project?.
I set up this project below where the microcontroller generates two PWM inverted 180° from each other with a duty cycle of 50%, 60 Hz.

I pass this PWM through LM386 to amplify the signal and then connect the LM386 output to the IRFZ44N MOSFET gate which is connected to a transformer with a center band 12-0-12.
This transformer has two windings on the 12 V primary and one on the 127 V secondary.
Then the common terminal of the coils (center terminal) changes to 12 V.
The two side coil terminals are connected, one on each MOSFET bridge.

But my problem is a voltage drop.
My transformer is designed for more than
1000 W is wanting to connect a 400 W load.
but when I turn it on it lowers the voltage to 30 Vac.

Does anyone know what's wrong?
Or if  to be 12-0-12 V winding it would have to be 24 V battery is it for 12 V 06V-0-06V winding?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited and reposted a new image

Comment: That image is a bit better. (It's still a bit 1990s quality though.) What is the LM386 output waveform like? The LM386 seems an odd choice as a MOSFET driver. 12 V is the correct supply for a 12 - 0 winding although 12 V RMS will peak at \$ 12 \sqrt 2 \$ so it could probably take about 50% more.

Comment: the output of lm386 is a 12v pwm.
my transformer was already made in another company, it already arrived with the defined set with 12v-0-12v.
but as you said its voltage would have to be 12 * 0.707 = 8V?.
would 8v-0-8v be correct?
would you have any solution to lower the voltage from 12v to 8v?

Comment: You should still inspect the LM386 output waveform on an oscilloscope. I said the opposite: a 12 V primary may be capable of almost 18 V. With 12 V the transformer is under-utilised but operating safely.

Comment: I tested it in practice.
checked the output of lm386 with an oscilloscope, everything is fine.
the output is the same as the input, but with amplified signal

Comment: there are no distortions, even when I put something at the output of the transformer that lowers the voltage

Comment: So, keep on going. How is the 12 V supply holding up during loading? What is the waveform on the MOSFET drains unloaded and loaded? It would be better to post the images rather than just assure us that it's "fine".

Comment: the battery is stationary at 12v per 100A.
It's my oscilloscope, it's automotive, it might not capture all the waveforms, but I'll still send photos